# Time Complexity (with a list of elements)

Tags: time-complexity

Just out of curiosity. Let's say I have a list which contain N elements(which will repeat) and a function which will return the frequency of these elements. I think the time complexity of this program should be O(N) right? As the function just need to loop through N and check whether the elements is already exist, if yes, +=, else = 1. Okay, so my friend and I have an argument as, how about if we need to multiple the elements with its frequency as well? And maybe divided by its total number? My friend think the complexity should be O(N^2) but it doesn't sounds right for me. What do you think, and why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you will record the frequencies. If you will be using an array they for each += you need to find the previous frequency value first, the complexity is quadratic. However if you maintain a hash table structure, on which access is instant on average, the complexity would be linear.

Comment: if we are using hash table, the complexity is still O(N)? Even though the number of list is huge and need to multiply its frequency(for each elements) as well?

Comment: If the number of items are huge you can allocate a huge hash table so that table enlargement is not an issue, and hash collisions will be rare. 

If you need to make additional calculations on the result that is a different problem and you should be more concrete of what you want to do. For example if you want to multiply frequencies with values in list, you need to iterate over keys of the hashtable and multiply them with the values. This will be a second step and total complexity will still be O(N).

Comment: I see, thank you so much for your clear explanations!